# Answer is now undefined, was working and suddenly stopped

Tags: javascript

Im trying to create a unit converter which does simple task of converting things like cm to mm and mm to ft etc. I had the code working perfectly then all of a sudden i get error message answer is undefined?

Was currently working now does not.

```
function calc() {
    let input = document.querySelector("#input").value;
    let unit = document.querySelector("#unit").value;
    let unit1 = document.querySelector("#unit1").value;
    let answer;

    if (unit == "mm" && unit1 == "cm") {
        answer = input * 10;
    } else if (unit == "cm" && unit1 == "mm") {
        answer = input / 10;
    } else if (unit == "ft" && unit1 == "cm") {
        answer = input / 30.48;
    }

    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = answer.toFixed(1);
}
```

cant understand why answer is not defined as it was working and nothign has been changed that i can see.

Comment: seems like you are missing other combos of options.

Comment: ^^ For instance, `unit = "ft"` and `unit1 = "mm"`.

Comment: Side note: It's best to use variable names that provide some context for what the variable contains. For instance, `fromUnits` and `toUnits` might be useful here.

Comment: but that doesnt explain why all of a sudden the converter stopped working. what i had was working 100% for various outcomes now doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. seems like it is working fine.

```js
function calc() {
  let input = document.querySelector("#input").value;
  let unit = document.querySelector("#unit").value;
  let unit1 = document.querySelector("#unit1").value;
  let answer;

  if (unit == "mm" && unit1 == "cm") {
    answer = input * 10;
  } else if (unit == "cm" && unit1 == "mm") {
    answer = input / 10;
  } else if (unit == "ft" && unit1 == "cm") {
    answer = input / 30.48;
  } else {
    answer = input;
    alert("Please check your unit and unit1");
    //added this code to check if you are entering the right values
  }
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = answer.toFixed(1);
}
```

```html
input : <input type="text" id="input" /> <br/>
unit : <input type="text" id="unit" /> <br/>
unit1 : <input type="text" id="unit1" /> <br/>

<input type="submit" onclick="calc()" value="sum"/> <br/>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: now its saying TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

Comment: can you add your HTML in your question?

Comment: i have just found it there was a type error on one of my HTML elements id

Comment: yes i have spent the last 45 mins trying to solve just that :(